# Requests password on every open while transaction is on SKPaymentQueue

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, in-app-purchase, storekit

I have an `iOS` app with non-consumable `IAP Apple` hosted content. The downloads are very large (~500MB).

While downloading the content, I have to keep the transaction "open", and only finish the transaction once the download is complete.

The problem with this is, `Store Kit` will automatically request to re-authenticate every time I move the app from background to foreground (or open the app) while a transaction is on the queue.

So, if I start a download, press the home button, return to app, `Store Kit` will request me to login.

It doesn't even matter if I re-login or just press "Cancel", the download will continue.

Is there anyway to get rid of this re-authentication request?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SKPaymentTransactionStateDeferred` to avoid that. On start up try to restore all transactions except those with `SKPaymentTransactionStateDeferred` state.

**Objective-C:**

```
NSArray *transactionsInQ = [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] transactions];
for(SKPaymentTransaction *transaction in transactionsInQ) {
    if(transaction.transactionState != SKPaymentTransactionStateDeferred) {
        // your code
    }
}
```

**Swift:**

```
let transactionsInQ = SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().transactions
for transaction in transactionsInQ {
    if (transaction.transactionState != .Deferred) {
         // your code
    }
}
```

Comment: Well I'm not actually doing anything on load. I just get a notification that my transaction is in the restored or purchased state, and then re-authentication. None of the transactions are in the deferred state.